# How to pop up a dialog when tapping on POI on OSMdroid map?

Tags: android, dialog, osmdroid

i want to pop up a dialog box containing the details(ex: longitude, latitude, description and thumbnail image extracted from SQLite Db ) whenever i tap on particular POI which was previously set up on OSM map. I would be grateful if anyone could help me...

Comment: I tried using:  dialog.setMessage(overLayItem1.getSnippet()); where i could retrieve latitude and longitude values from the onTouchEvent() method. But i couldn't get the thumbnail view of the image in the dialog.

Comment: i got the markers on the map. Need to pop up a dialog box from the marker consisting above mentioned details. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom dialog with a  imageview that you can set the image to?

Comment: no. im new to android. can you share me a example of how to do that?

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912546/android-osmdriod-map-pop-up-dialog-box-when-clicking-a-marker

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how you would create a custom dialog with textviews and imageview for your thumbnail

```
<RelativeLayout  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/geo_image" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView   
android:id="@+id/player_name"
android:layout_below="@id/geo_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then extend Dialog

```
private Dialog constructYourDialog(){
   //Preparing views
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.***your_xml_name***, (ViewGroup)   findViewById(R.id.***Yout view id***));
//Building dialog
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);

  builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();
});
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

       dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
 builder.setNeutralButton("Show me more", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
return alert;
```

}